# MongoDB and Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I've deployed my NodeJS app to Heroku. I'm using MongoDB Atlas (ex. mlab) as my database. I'd like to set up Network Access, but it's imposible to get app IP (Heroku team official statement).
So I have to make my MongoDB cluster open for everybody in IP whitelist. Are there any ways to make it secure?

Comment: Sure. Use a long, complicated password.

Comment: or use x.509 authentication